# Why i'm getting null value instead of aggregated response?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform min aggregation using nested aggregation in elasticsearch but still getting null values..

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "FirstName": "Cheryl"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "art": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "art"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "min_price": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "art.Income"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mappings :

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "art": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "FirstName": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "Price": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us your mapping and a data sample in order to help us to resolve your case?

Comment: PUT /my_index
{   
    "mappings": {
        "properties" : {
            "art" : { 
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                    "FirstName" : { "type" : "text" },
                    "Price" : { "type" : "integer" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: This is my mapping..

Comment: Ok but you want to aggregate on Income and the field in the mapping is Price. Are you sure you just dont have a typo in your query ? Can you provide us with the result of GET my_index/_mapping ?

Comment: I've tried with both Income and price but still it gives null

Comment: Ok, and can you give us a sample of data that you use?

Comment: How can i send it doesn't allow me to send csv file